# Issue with Modified Bubble Sort Algorithm

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, integer

Ok I'm trying to write an algorithm for sorting an array, in this case an array of random integers. I know QuickSort or similar would obviously more efficient, but for this assignment I have to basically make a modified version of the inefficient Bubble Sort algorithm.

The idea is to compare integers across a gap. After each pass, the gap is supposed to be cut in half. If value on left is greater than value on right, they are swapped. Execution is supposed to continue until no swaps occurs or gap is 1. I'm usually pretty descent at this sort of thing but it seems that I'm missing something. For some reason the algorithm isn't sorting my arrays.

Here is my code. Maybe someone can see what I'm missing:

```
public class ShellArray
{
    private int capacity;
    private int [] randArray;
    private static final int RANGE = 200;               //Range set to 200 for possible integers.

    public ShellArray(int capacity)
    {
        this.capacity = capacity;
        randArray = new int[capacity];
        populate(randArray, RANGE, capacity);
    }

    /**************************************************************************************************************************************************
    //
    //Populates array with random integers within given range.
    //
    ***************************************************************************************************************************************************/

    private static void populate(int [] myArray, int numRange, int extent)
    {
        Random r = new Random();

        for (int i = 0; i < extent; i++)
            myArray[i] = (r.nextInt(numRange)+1);
    }

    /**************************************************************************************************************************************************
    //
    //The first version of shellSort calls the second version with min value as 0 and max as length of randArray-1. Takes no parameters.
    //
    ***************************************************************************************************************************************************/
    public void shellSort()
    {
        shellSort(0, randArray.length-1);
    }

    /**************************************************************************************************************************************************
    //
    // shellSort which takes min and max parameters. Calculates gap at center, across which values are compared. Passes continue until gap size is 1
    // and array is sorted.
    // Uses boolean sorted to indicate when array is sorted so passes don't continue needelessly after array is sorted. Essentially, if no values
    // are swapped after a pass, we know array is sorted and sorted is not set to false.
    //
    // Outer for loop controls position of final value. Since largest value is bubbled to end, position decreases by 1 after each pass.
    // After each pass, size of gap is cut in half, as long as gap is 2 or greater. Otherwise gap would become too small.
    // Inner for loop controls the index values to be compared.
    // Uses swap method to swap values which are not in the correct order.
    // Array is printed after each pass.
    //
    ***************************************************************************************************************************************************/

    public void shellSort(int min, int max)
    {
        String result;
        int gap;
        int j = 0;
        int size = randArray.length-1;
        boolean swapped;

        for(gap = size/2; gap <= 0; gap = gap/2)
        {
            swapped = true;

            while (swapped)
            {   
                swapped = false;
                int comp;

                for(comp = 0; comp+gap <= size; comp++)
                {
                    if (randArray[comp] > randArray[comp+gap])
                    {
                        swap(comp, comp+gap);
                        swapped = true;        //swapped set to true if any element is swapped with another.
                    }
                    else
                        swapped = false;
                }
            }

            result = "";
            for(int y = 0; y < randArray.length; y++)
            {
                result += randArray[y] + " ";
                j++;
            }

            System.out.println("Pass " +j+": " +result+"\n");
         }
    }

    /**************************************************************************************************************************************************
    //
    // Swaps two values in the array.
    //
    ***************************************************************************************************************************************************/

    private void swap(int index1, int index2)
    {
        int temp = randArray[index1];
        randArray[index1] = randArray[index2];
        randArray[index2] = temp;
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        String result = "";

        for(int y = 0; y < randArray.length; y++)
            result += randArray[y] +" ";

        return result;
    }

}
```

Comment: Hello and I guess welcome on SO. Pleas when posting a question on here add your expected output and the program's output. We obviously understand what sorting means but simply saying your program doesn't work is not enough. Does it start sorting and stops? Does it have a weird behavior ? ...

Comment: What you are describing is a [shellsort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shellsort).  Depending on the gap sequence you use, it can be a fairly efficient sort -- certainly more efficient in the worst-case asymptotic limit than straight comparison sorts such as insertion sort (or bubble sort).

Comment: Note - [shellsort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shellsort) is a gapped version of insertion short. If you actually wanted a gapped version of bubble sort you would use [comb sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comb_sort), but that doesn't seem to be the case with the example code.

Comment: Well I really can't get this to work. My output is still out of order every time. For example, for an array with 7 random integers, I get output: 181 169 36 1 60 12 169. Obviously not sorted at all. See above I tried making some changes to shellSort(...) in the while loop but this didn't help. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong? I'm not sure If I'm understanding correctly what John meant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't provided the details of your assignment, but the idea of a sort along these lines is that the final stage (i.e. with `gap == 1`) is a *bona fide* standard sort all on its own -- in this case, I guess a bubble sort -- and the prior stages pre-treat the input so that the efficiency of that final sort is much better than for random input.  At least for `gap == 1`, then, you must repeat the sort loop until there are no swaps.

There are two main variations possible here, and you haven't given us the information to know which you want:

- The first variation shrinks the gap after each iteration of the sort loop until it reaches 1, then repeats with that gap until there are no more swaps.
- The second variation repeats the sort loop with the same gap until there are no swaps, then shrinks the gap and repeats.

My guess would be that you want the second, as that's the one that is actually a shell sort (of an unusual flavor).  Even though it might sound like it would be less efficient than the other, there's a good chance that it's *more* efficient, because devoting a small amount of additional effort when the gap is large accomplishes larger element movements in fewer steps.

Comment: Option 2 is definitely the one I want  .Ok well I've made some changes along those lines to my shellSort method but now I get indefinite recursion (I think). I'm not sure why this is happening. Please see the modifications I made in the shellSort method. Maybe you can see what I'm doing wrong

Comment: @J'Zargo, I don't see any reason to expect the sort to fail to terminate, but there certainly is an error.  You intend to use the `swapped` variable to memorialize whether any swaps are performed in one run of the the innermost sort loop, and accordingly you set it to `false` before entering that loop.  You should not, however, ever set it back to `false` within the inner loop -- that makes it record only whether *the last* comparison resulted in a swap, not whether *any* comparison resulted in a swap.